# Loop for existing directories in a path

Tags: python

I'd like to loop over all directories in a path in Python. So I tried something like the following:

```
import os, glob, sys

os.chdir('/')
dir_list = glob.glob('*')
for wd in dir_list if os.path.isdir(wd) is True:
    print(wd + " is a directory.")
```

It seems I have some kind of `syntax error`. What should I be doing instead of `is True`? I had thought that `os.path.isdir()` returns a `boolean`.

Comment: If you want all directory entries, `os.listdir(.)` is usually better than `glob.glob('*')` (especially if you want your code to do the right thing on Windows, without you having to think about Windows at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing generator expressions with a for loop. You can't do that. Put the `if` statement on it's own line:

```
for wd in dir_list:
    if os.path.isdir(wd):
        print(wd + " is a directory.")
```

Note that you do not need to test for `is True`; that's exactly what the `if` statement does already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the creation of the iterator from the `for`, you could do it in one line with this:

```
for wd in (x for x in dir_list if os.path.isdir(x)):
```

I do not think is nice looking, I guess it would be better if you do it in a previous line but is your call anyway.